# How to read data one by one from files into matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, file, input, line

I have a file which is like this:

```
PoreCount=   9
ThroatCount= 10
0   1.16667 -0.666667   0
1   1.16667 -0.333333   0
2   1.16667  0          0
3   1.5     -0.666667   0
4   1.5     -0.333333   0
5   1.5      0          0
6   1.83333 -0.666667   0
7   1.83333 -0.333333   0
8   1.83333  0          0
0   0   1   0.0610206   0.333333    0
1   0   3   0.0606029   0.333333    0
2   1   2   0.0601841   0.333333    0
3   1   4   0.0612494   0.333333    0
4   3   4   0.0593242   0.333333    0
5   3   6   0.0589063   0.333333    0
6   4   5   0.0599607   0.333333    0
7   4   7   0.0595583   0.333333    0
8   6   7   0.0591209   0.333333    0
9   7   8   0.0601974   0.333333    0
```

You can see:
There are two kinds of object in here, P and T. 
There are 9 P s and 10 Ts. 
There are 4 kinds of information about P, 1 integer and 3 floating point numbers. 
There are 6 kinds of information about T, 3 integers and 3 floating point numbers.

Now I need the matlab program knows how many P and T is there, and then read every kind of information about P into a 1-D array, and every kind of information about T into a 1-D array.

So there will be 4 column arrays to store P information. and 6 column arrays to store T information.

Based on my knowledge, I write the following program. And it doesn't work, no need to say. Please help me out.

```
prompt = 'Please enter the file name: ';
FileName = input(prompt, 's');
SaturationFile=fopen(FileName);

PoreCount  =fscanf(SaturationFile, 'PoreCount  = %d\n', 1);
ThroatCount=fscanf(SaturationFile, 'ThroatCount= %d\n', 1);

% P =fscanf(SaturationFile, '%d%f%f%f\n', PoreCount);
% P=zeros(4, 1);
PI=zeros(PoreCount, 1);
PX=zeros(PoreCount, 1);
PY=zeros(PoreCount, 1);
PS=zeros(PoreCount, 1);

% T =fscanf(SaturationFile, '%f', [ThroatCount, 6]);
TI=zeros(ThroatCount, 1);
Tb=zeros(ThroatCount, 1);
Te=zeros(ThroatCount, 1);
TA=zeros(ThroatCount, 1);
TL=zeros(ThroatCount, 1);
TS=zeros(ThroatCount, 1);

for i=1:PoreCount
%     P=fscanf(SaturationFile, '%d');
%     PI(i)=P(i, 1);
%     PX(i)=P(i, 2);
%     PY(i)=P(i, 3);
%     PS(i)=P(i, 4);
    PI(i)=fscanf(SaturationFile, '%d'  , 1);
    PX(i)=fscanf(SaturationFile, '%f'  , 1);
    PY(i)=fscanf(SaturationFile, '%f'  , 1);
    PS(i)=fscanf(SaturationFile, '%d\n', 1);
end

for i=1:ThroatCount
    TI(i)=fscanf(SaturationFile, '%d'  , 1);
    Tb(i)=fscanf(SaturationFile, '%d'  , 1);
    Te(i)=fscanf(SaturationFile, '%d'  , 1);
    TA(i)=fscanf(SaturationFile, '%f'  , 1);
    TL(i)=fscanf(SaturationFile, '%f'  , 1);
    TS(i)=fscanf(SaturationFile, '%d\n', 1);
end
```

error message:

```
In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same.
    Error in NetworkSaturationPlot (line 29)
        PI(i)=fscanf(SaturationFile, '%d'  , 1);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  If it yields an error, please [edit] your question to include the error.

Comment: Thanks, I added the error message, I don't under stand why the PI(i), the scalar will have the dimension problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get two structures Ttmp and Ptmp, which are 1D cell arrays, each cell array contains the data from a single column. These cell arrays are then turned into regular vectors

```
clear all;close all;clc

SaturationFile=fopen('./data.txt');
PoreCount  =fscanf(SaturationFile, 'PoreCount  = %d\n', 1);
ThroatCount=fscanf(SaturationFile, 'ThroatCount= %d\n', 1);
Ptmp=textscan(SaturationFile,'%u %f %f %u',PoreCount);    
Ttmp=textscan(SaturationFile,'%u %u %u %f %f %d',ThroatCount);

PI=Ptmp{1};
PX=Ptmp{2};
PY=Ptmp{3};
PS=Ptmp{4};


TI=Ttmp{1};
TB=Ttmp{2};
TE=Ttmp{3};
TL=Ttmp{4};
TA=Ttmp{5};
TS=Ttmp{6};
fclose(SaturationFile);
```

Comment: P=textscan (...) works, and read it into a cell matrix, but I cannot use cell2mat, because it need the matrix contents be the same type

Comment: another option is to take the output of textscan and in a for loop take the contents of P and T (at each element) and place them into arrays. does that make sense?

Comment: I believe read in them one by one is a better option. But how to do that? Look, actually, I wanted to read it one by one. But my syntax seems not appropriate.

Comment: i have edited the answer to include loops to create the arrays P & T, let me know if this is what you are looking for

Comment: Thanks! This one got error: Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in NetworkSaturationPlot (line 11)
    PI(jj,:)=Ptmp{jj}; I am not sure what this sentence do! I checked the data, the Ptmp read in 4 cells and each cell is the column vector, and Ttmp read in 6 cells, each cell is also the column vector. Now what I need to do is to put the each cell into a separate column vectors. For example, PI PX PY PS for pores, and TI TB TE TL TA TS for throats

Comment: i have updated the response, is that more what you are looking for? the P array has each entry from Ptmp in each row of P. Now P gets broken into the individual vectors as asked

Comment: Thank you very much for all these inputs. I tried, this one don't work either. Looks like the PX PY TL TA, which all should be floating point numbers, are all rounded to integers. Is there any way to fix these?

Comment: now it has floating point and integer values per the input file. that's what the %f and %u represent